# Match Multiple Lookup Array

Tags: excel, vba

Currently working on my final project thesis, i need some excel calculation for manual analytic section on the report.

So here the problem,

I need to define position of each facelets.

In example position Facelets 1 is 9. (Check picture below)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X05IG.png]

So far, i get the way to reach that by transpose each row to 1 column. Like picture below and use excel function MATCH() to get the relative position.

=MATCH(1;A1:A18;0)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEDPD.png]

Is there a way to get relative position without transpose the lookup array?

I have try use multiselect row (example A1:A3;B1:B3;), but it return errors.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: do you have the Key somewhere?  are the values always unique?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes it is... the value always unique... i just need the position of each facelets... Reference of position is at the first image, the right one (with gray background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a "Key" to return the correct location:

```
=INDEX($N$1:$Y$9,
   AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$L$9)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$L$9))+1)/($A$1:$L$9=AB2),1),
   AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A$1:$L$9)-MIN(COLUMN($A$1:$L$9))+1)/($A$1:$L$9=AB2),1))
```

As long as the two areas are the same size and the values unique this will return the location on the "Key"

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer Scott.

I've tried your formula and got an error. Is there something wrong with my pasted formula?

https://imgur.com/a/2sajz9l

Comment: @YohanesIsaAnantoTriPratiwi you may need to change all the `,` to `;` for your local settings.